# does the restify client http post callback function have the limitation of the character length?

Tags: restify

when i call client http post in restify like this:

```
client.post( '/hdapi/User/sendSms',jssendSms, function(hdregistererr,hdregisterreq,hdregisterres,hdregisterobj)
```

it failed and print the error info:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: callback (func) is required
    at HttpClient.request (/root/node_modules/restify-clients/lib/HttpClient.js:716:12)
    at HttpClient.post (/root/node_modules/restify-clients/lib/HttpClient.js:667:18)
    at why (/root/myapp/app.js:354:17)
```

when i changed those codes to

```
client.post( '/hdapi/User/sendSms',jssendSms,
function(hdregerr,hdregreq,hdregres,hdregobj) {
```

it passed, so does the restify client http post callback function have the limitation of the character length ?

Comment: I doubt it. Are you having a problem with what you receive from the request?

Comment: Actually , the nodejs app failed and i can't get anything from the server.